# D3.JS correct x scale to use for time duration starting from 0

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My x data looks like "01:11", "02:50", "01:02:20" etc.  representing hours, minutes and seconds.

I'm struggling to tell if I should use a linear or a time scale? Advise would be great.

Comment: because its time so you you should use time scale.

Comment: @Cyril Even though it is time as in a count or timeline not a date time?

Comment: It sounds like a linear scale (with appropriate formatting for the axis labels) would be best here.